# Uninitialized value $fh when attempting to read from file

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I have written following code to read the files in the reverse order of input and print the values to command line.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
if(@ARGV == 0)
{
        die "No file name given \n";
}
my @argarr;
while(@ARGV != 0)
{
        my $tmp = pop @ARGV;
        push @argarr, $tmp;
}
foreach(@argarr)
{
        #print $_;
        #print "\n";
        if (! open my $fh , "< $_")
        {
           print "unable to open $_\n";
        }
        while(<$fh>)
        {
                chomp;
                print "$_\n";
        }
}
```

However it is not working as expected. Instead of printing the files to STDOUT it is showing below error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $fh in <HANDLE> at ./mtac.pl line 23.
readline() on unopened filehandle at ./mtac.pl line 23.
```

Please help.

Comment: Add a `use strict;` at the top and you'll get a pretty clear hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: The error message that Calle eludes to, which you'll see after after adding the `strict` pragma, is telling you that you have a scoping issue.  `$fh` is declared in the wrong scope.

Comment: Ok i got the issue. I am declaring $fh inside the if block so it is not available to the while loop. Thanks Calle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say you should always use `use strict` at the top of script.It will give you the hint if variables are not properly scoped
in your script.

This will do the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if(@ARGV == 0)
{
        die "No file name given \n";
}
my @argarr = reverse @ARGV;
foreach(@argarr)
{
        my $fh;
        unless(open $fh, '<', $_){
            warn "unable to open file $_ : $! \n";
            next;
         }
        while(<$fh>)
        {
                chomp;
                print "$_\n";
        }
close($fh);
}
```

Comment: The correct place to put `my $fh` is inside the `foreach` loop. That will also close the handle for each new file name. You can also get rid of `@argarr` with `for (reverse @ARGV)`.

Comment: You should explain what you think is wrong with the OP's code that you have fixed in your version. Code-only solutions are never very useful as they leave people (others who come here for help with a similar issue as well as the OP) unable to do anything for themselves beyond copy-pasting your code. It is highly unlikely that this will work as drop-in code for many situations, and some narrative to explain what problems you have fixed and how your code works is pretty much *de rigeur*

Answer (score 2):

`$fh` scalar is lexicaly scoped and visible only inside `if` branch

```
    if (! open my $fh , "< $_") { .. }
```

You can resolve this with

```
    open my $fh , "<", $_ or print("$! $_"), next;
```

or

```
   my $ok = open my $fh , "<", $_;
   if (!$ok) { print("$! $_"); next; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the scope of `$fh` is limited to the block where it's initialized. Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

die "No file names given\n" unless @ARGV;

for my $file (reverse(@ARGV)) {
    next unless -f $file;
    open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open file [$file]: $!\n";

    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        say;
    }

    close($fh);
}
```